# What type of audio output does this symbol represent?

Tags: audio, circuit-design, symbol, digital-audio

I have this picture. I want **left**, **left ground**, **right** and **right ground** output. Pin. But I can't understand it. Can somebody please help me. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Google image search on a cropped image would have helped.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a female TRS connector: (Image from [here](http://9.hmtae.aufraeumfee.de/audio-jack-schematic.html))

[image]

So you would have left audio on the tip, right audio on the ring, and GBUF on the sleeve.  (I'm assuming GBUF is the common ground for the 2 audio channels, but your schematic doesn't show it.)

Comment: Alright. It's actually not complete schematic. That was helpful though. Thanks